# Show if $u$ and $v$ (non zero vectors) are perpendicular, then they are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let u and v be non zero vectors in Rˆn. Show if u and v are perpendicular, then {u,v} is linearly independent.

I started my proof as following:

If $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular, then $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$

So we can write $u_1 v_1 + \cdots + u_n v_n = 0$.

As $u$ and $v$ are non zero vectors there may exist a scalar $k$ that satisfies the identity.

Thus, $k = 0$ and we have a linearly independent combination of $u$ and $v$.

Is it right? wrong? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is not clear.

Let $t,s$ be scalars such that $tu+sv=0.$ Then

$$0=<u,tu+sv>=t<u,u>+s<u,v>=t||u||^2.$$

This shows that $t=0$, since $||u||^2 \ne 0.$ Hence $sv=0$. Since $v \ne 0$, we get $s=0.$

Comment: I know <u,v> = 0 because u and v are perpendicular, but why <u, tu + sv> = 0?

Comment: Because tu+ sv= 0!  And <u, 0>= 0 for any u.